# Not able to perform connectivity tests in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

While exploring Azure Virtual Networks, I tried to delete NetworkWatcherRG resource group. The deletion was not successful as it seems. After that I am not able to run any connectivity tests.

The error seems to be with the process of deletion of NetworkWatcherRG. Here is the raw format of the error provided by Azure.

```
  "message": "Cannot deploy to resource group NetworkWatcherRG: deleting.",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Cannot deploy to resource group NetworkWatcherRG: deleting.\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/KqF9_ozsrMOn.js:2:14004\n    at s (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fcfeK376smSa.js:17:2614)\n    at Object.next (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fcfeK376smSa.js:17:1907)\n    at o (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fcfeK376smSa.js:17:1680)",
  "extension": "Microsoft_Azure_Network"
```

I have waited for more than 2 hours to complete the deletion process, but the same error is popping up.

Comment: hello , As you have deleted NetworkWatcherRG and till its in deleting state you will not be able to perform connectivity tests because it will try to deploy the new network watcher in the same resource group. Once the deletion completes please run the connectivity test , so that it can create a new RG for the network watcher and run successfully.

Comment: What is the timeline for deletion of the NetworkWatcherRG? Any ideas? I have waited for around 2 hours, but no luck!

Comment: not sure on time,, can you please tell me if what is the status of NetworkWatcherRG resource group now ?like you can check the status from activity logs ?

Comment: NetworkWatcherRG seems to be a parent Resource group. There is no such thing as "status". It is shown with a location where it is deployed and that's all.

Comment: The log for the error is already shown in the question posted. Other than that I do not have access to any other logs.

Comment: I tested it , first deleted the RG , then created a connection troubleshoot and it automattically watcher in RG and then added the extension to the VM , you can refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/R7I6Iiw.png). so i would suggest to please try logging out from portal and logging in again or you can try logging in from private window.

Comment: hello @hundredmiles ,may i please know if  the is issue resolved for you or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: hello @AnsumanBal-MT, Since NetworkWatcherRG could not be deleted even after 2 hours, I deleted the subscription and the error was gone due to that. Unfortunately after reactivating the subscription the issue could not be reproduced. So, as of now, I have closed this with the Azure customer support as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have posted says that the NetworkWatcherRG resource group is stuck at deleting. So I would request you to try the below provided steps to delete the resource group completely:

-Open a web browser and navigate to https://resources.azure.com

-Log-in to the appropriate Azure account.

-In the blade on the left side of the browser, expand subscriptions, then expand the desired subscription name.

-In the blade on the left side of the browser, expand resource groups.

-Under resource groups, click on the Resource Group "NetworkWatcherRG".

-Near the top of the content window of the browser, select the Read/Write push button

-Select the Actions(POST, DELETE) tab on the NetworkWatcherRG resource group within the resource explorer and click on Delete. It should give a green tick if succeeded and red exclamation with the error message at the bottom of the page, in case it fails.

Confirm if the resource group is deleted. (It will take some time to delete, so please wait for at least 15 mins).

Once you confirm that it is deleted, you can enable Network watcher for all the regions where you have Vnets deployed via Azure portal following the below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-create#create-a-network-watcher-in-the-portal

After you have enabled all the Vnet regions in your Network Watcher, you can check if the connectivity tests are working.

Comment: The issue seemed to be an exceptional case which could not be reproduced. Please refer to my last comment against my post.